# How to "dense" a data frame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame looks like:

```
item_id  week_id  sale amount
1           1         10
1           2         12
1           3         15
2           1         4
2           2         7
2           3         9
```

I want to transform this dataframe to a new data frame looks like:

```
item_id   week_1     week_2     week_3
1          10          12         15
2          4            7          9
```

This can be easily done in R, but I don't know how to do it using Spark API, with Scala.

Comment: Pivot is your friend! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `groupBy.pivot` and then aggregate the *sale_amount* column, in this case, you can take the first value from each combination ids of item and week if there are no more than one row within each combination:

```
df.groupBy("item_id").pivot("week_id").agg(first("sale_amount")).show
+-------+---+---+---+
|item_id|  1|  2|  3|
+-------+---+---+---+
|      1| 10| 12| 15|
|      2|  4|  7|  9|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

You can use other aggregation functions if there are more than one row for each combination of `item_id` and `week_id`, the *sum* for instance:

```
df.groupBy("item_id").pivot("week_id").agg(sum("sale_amount")).show
+-------+---+---+---+
|item_id|  1|  2|  3|
+-------+---+---+---+
|      1| 10| 12| 15|
|      2|  4|  7|  9|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

To get proper column names, you can transform the `week_id` column before pivoting:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

(df.withColumn("week_id", concat(lit("week_"), df("week_id"))).
    groupBy("item_id").pivot("week_id").agg(first("sale_amount")).show)

+-------+------+------+------+
|item_id|week_1|week_2|week_3|
+-------+------+------+------+
|      1|    10|    12|    15|
|      2|     4|     7|     9|
+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, how to auto fill "0" if there is no value "week_id" for some item_id?

Comment: You can use `na.fill(0)` to fill missing values with 0. `df.withColumn("week_id", concat(lit("week_"), df("week_id"))).groupBy("item_id").pivot("week_id").agg(first("sale_amount")).na.fill(0).show)`